# 'And' vs 'or' in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> The team can pair James — and whoever else might be coming — with Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball **and** Kyle Kuzma.

I saw the sentence from a news article. I doubt the usage of "and" here.

From my understanding, 'pair' denotes two parties. So, the team can separately pair *James with Brandon Ingram*, *James with Lonzo Ball* or *James with Kyle Kuzma*. Then the sentence should be:

> The team can pair James — and whoever else might be coming — with Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball **or** Kyle Kuzma.

But is this possible to **pair James with Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball and Kyle Kuzma**? What would it mean — if possible/correct — *to pair James with Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball and Kyle Kuzma*?

[The full source](https://www.yahoo.com/sports/lebron-james-signs-four-year-154-million-deal-lakers-001301850.html).

Comment: Are you referring to one event (the pairing), or multiple events? In a single pairing, it can only be *or*.

Comment: @user3169 I am not sure what you mean, but you can refer to the full source in my answer.

Comment: The article is just plain wrong. Things that are paired are grouped into sets of two. This is a case of James and an unknown man being grouped into a set of five. It is not a pairing. If it was a pairing, user3169 would be definitely right. Having skimmed the article I can see that Rob delivers a good answer at explaining the correct use of "and". Note that Rob does not use the word "pair" in his answer but correctly uses "group".

Comment: @Smartybartfast , actually Rob thought the sentence is correct. He interpreted *My interpretation of this is as follows. James has not arrived. There are 2 distinct groups Group A and Group B.*  That's why he think it's right. What's your opinion about the sentence I quoted?

Comment: Rob is correct that it should be **and**. *If* the sport consisted of just two people from each team playing at a time I would accept either **and** or **or** because "they can pair James with Brandon **and** they can pair James with Lonzo **and** James with Kyle" (even if not at the same time) *or* "they can pair James with Brandon or pair James with Lonzo etc." because both are valid ways of listing the sets of possible pairs. But because it's a five player team it must be **group**, not **pair**, and even if I accepted pair as a synomyn for "make a group of 5" it would have to be **"and**.

Comment: @Smartybartfast, Although it's a 5-player sport, the partnership/pairing is still very common in NBA teams. Remember Michael Jordon paired with Scottie Pippen, Karl Malone paired with John Stockton, and etc. Those are perfect pairs in NBA history. I think Lakers is trying to work this kind of pair(s) out here. It could be *James with Brandon Ingram, James with Lonzo Ball or James with Kyle Kuzma*. So, I think James's answer --I have accepted it-- is right.  What do you think?

Comment: That passage is so horribly ungrammatical, no-one should infer anything from it; certainly not anything about 'And' vs 'or'. The passage is generally understandable, colloquially, but that’s not due to grammar or syntax and I suggest no clear or specific meaning is comprehensible. Please, choose a different passage…

Comment: @dan Mr Goodwin may be right that sports writers are not necessarily operating at the vanguard of the literary craft, but you should at least pick one of the other answers besides James's. Its reasoning is patently wrong in this case, as noted by the downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the use of **and** is intentional.

[**Pair**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pair) does normally mean two people:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> noun
>
> **b** : a partnership especially of two players in a contest against another partnership
>
> transitive verb
>
> **1 a** : to make a pair of —often used with *off* or *up* · *paired* off the animals
>   **b** : to cause to be a member of a pair
>   **c** : to arrange a voting pair between
>
> **2** : to arrange in pairs
>
> intransitive verb
>
> **1** : to constitute a member of a pair · a sock that didn't *pair*
>
> **2 a** : to become associated with another —often used with *off* or *up* · *paired* up with an old friend
>
> **b** : to become grouped or separated into pairs —often used with off · paired off for the next dance

If the example sentence had been talking about forming groups of *more* than two people, my assumption would be that the word **group** would have been used instead. (Although **team up** would sound more natural, it would be awkward to write *the team can team up*.)

So, for the sake of argument, I'll assume that the sentence is talking about forming pairs—groups of two people.

Some people have not yet arrived: James and some other people.

Other people are presumably already there: Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball and Kyle Kuzma.

The key to determining that the final conjunction should be **and** rather than **or** is this:

> The team can pair James — ***and*** *whoever else might be coming* . . .

This is saying that it's not only *James* who will be paired with somebody, but also the other people coming (whoever they may be).

If these other people were not to be included in pairs, then I see little point in mentioning them—and certainly no point in mentioning them with this phrasing.

Assuming that two other people arrive with James, we can then breakdown and rephrase the sentence in the following manner:

The team will pair (in some fashion):

- James, Person 1 and Person 2 with
- Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball and Kyle Kuzma.

While it's true that James could be paired with Brandon Ingram or Lonzo Ball or Kyle Kuzma (and the same could be said for each other person with others), the sentence as written isn't describing a *specific* pairing (involving just James) but an overall group of people between all of whom pairings will be made.

Comment: I think this is spot on up until the very last paragraph. I would go so far as to say that we don't need any more context beyond what's in the article. Sports fans (the most likely readers of the article) will most likely know that Ingram, Ball, and Kuzma are three returning Lakers who will be paired with two new players: James and whoever else. That will give us five people for the team's starting lineup.

Comment: @cjl750 Point taken. Given this, I have removed that final paragraph.

Comment: Eh, @cjl750 was wrong about the last paragraph. You're probably right but there's nothing wrong with admitting that additional context could make it certain instead of just probable.

Comment: @lly Except that, in hindsight, I want to give a certain answer; other answers can give others. This situation seems like it's obviously about context and interpretation anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Just to offer a terser version of what [Mssrs Bassford](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/171423/52137) and [X](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/171012/52137) are saying above:

> From my understanding, 'pair' denotes two parties.

People can be loose about these things but, properly speaking, **yes**. A pair should be a joining of two items *or two sets of items*.

> ...the team can separately pair James with Brandon Ingram,... with Lonzo Ball, or... with Kyle Kuzma.

**Yes**, but that doesn't make much sense. Basketball teams don't typically operate in units of two players or normally involve set mentor/protégé relationships. You're *also* ignoring the unnamed player from James's side of the sentence.

> But is [it] possible to pair James with Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball and Kyle Kuzma? What would it mean...?

It would mean that he was being paired with the **group** consisting of Messrs Ingram, Ball, & Kuzma. In fact, that's what the writer *has* written: **James *and* a Player-to-Be-Decided-Later *are* going to paired as a unit with an established set of three known players**. Presumably, they will operate as a unit of five, the standard number for a basketball team's starters.

Answer (score 1):

The team can pair **James** — **and whoever else might be coming** — with Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball and Kyle Kuzma.

My interpretation of this is as follows. James has not arrived. 
There are 2 distinct groups **Group A** and **Group B**.

**Group A** has **not** arrived.

**Group B** has arrived

**Group A** members are [James and whoever else might be coming]

**Group B** members are [Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball and Kyle Kuzma]

Groups can be made with **"and"** for example [Brandon Ingram **and** Lonzo Ball **and** Kyle Kuzma]

rather than writing 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 5 to make a group you write commas.
My favorite numbers are 1,2,3,4 and 5. The comma represents an and.

The and is part of a list defining **Group B**

In conclusion it is **"and"** not **or**.

Answer (score 1):

### Both are incorrect

> The team can pair James — and whoever else might be coming — with Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball, **and** Kyle Kuzma.

This implies that James and Fred (as James said above) are getting paired with all three of Brandon, Lonzo and Kyle. Unless there happens to be another person with James, this is obviously impossible.

> The team can pair James — and whoever else might be coming — with Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball **or** Kyle Kuzma.

This implies that both James and Fred will only get paired with one of Brandon, Lonzo, and Kyle (thus both having the same partner). This, while possible, seems unlikely to me.

The correct way to state the sentence is:

> The team can pair James and whoever else might be coming **each** with **one of** Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball **and** Kyle Kuzma.

There are four things to note here:

1. Whether or not someone else is coming with James is important for the grammar of the sentence, so it is placed into the sentence properly
2. 'Each' is added, specifying that each of the people coming gets their own partner.
3. 'One of' is added, specifying that they each only get one partner, and not all three.
4. 'And' is used because we already specified 'one of' earlier, so 'or' would be incorrect.

Comment: @lly "They are coming with each one of these three men" isn't the sentence I proposed though. If you want to generalise what I said, then it would be, "The team can pair each of them with one of these three men" which isn't awkward at all IMO. As for the semantics, I took it to mean that one arriving player will be paired with one established player. I don't know much about Basketball, so that might be wrong. That seems to be what other people here are assuming though.

Answer (score -3):

> The team can pair James — and whoever else might be coming — with Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball and Kyle Kuzma.

Who was the writer referring to when he wrote, "...whoever else might be coming..."? It seems to me that this was a call back to the previous paragraph where the writer said:
.

> The Lakers had a large amount of cap space to work with. The team was
>   projected to have a little under $50 million to hand out. That put
>   them in the running to sign not just James, but potentially  **another**
>   top free agent.  (emphasis mine)

So, I interpret this to mean that (at the time the article was written), the writer is only expecting one additional top player to be signed up. It is this additional top player that is being referred to as '...whoever else might be coming...".  For the sake of simplicity, I will call this additional player Fred.

Now, what was meant by the opening sentence? I think the writer means that we will have James and Fred joining the Lakers, and they will each be individually paired with one player each from a group of existing players comprised of Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball and Kyle Kuzma. The writer is apparently not exactly sure who these two new players will be paired with, but he is confident that the pairs will be drawn from this small group of three.

Note: There are existing players other than the three named. Presumably, by not naming them, the writer is assuming that none of these existing players will be considered as pairs for James and Fred

Because the writer was focusing on the group from which pairs could be drawn he used 'and' when listing them. Could he have used 'or' instead? Yes, I think he could have used either 'and' or 'or' and it would not change the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: A side question: *a group of existing players comprising **of** Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball and Kyle Kuzma* or *a group of existing players comprising Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball and Kyle Kuzma*? I think *of* should not be there.

Comment: And if you remove — and whoever else might be coming — from the original sentence, *The team can pair James with Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball and Kyle Kuzma* doesn't look right. *The team can pair James with Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball or Kyle Kuzma* looks right to me.

Comment: @dan  You are 100% correct. 'Comprising of' cannot be defended, That is the problem when you redraft an answer, you sometimes are so focused on getting the whole message right that you get the details wrong.  This originally said 'comprised of', which I meant to change to 'comprising' but forgot to remove the 'of'. Some people would still be (and have been) critical of the use of 'comprised of', but I am of the school of thought that its use is acceptable and historic.

Comment: @dan  If you delete that part of the sentence, I think you would be better saying: "The team can pair James with Brandon Ingram, or Lonzo Ball or Kyle Kuzma." There is then no doubt that he will only be paired with one of them. But the sentence does include that part of the sentence, and I don't think you can say "The team can pair James and Fred with Brandon Ingram, or Lonzo Ball or Kyle Kuzma.", which is why I worded my answer as I did. I suspect that this article was quickly put together shortly after James' announcement, and the writer would have written it differently if given more time.

Comment: I gotta downvote this because I just can't see this interpretation making any sense in the context of basketball. Unless the article were about some kind of mentorship between James and one of the other three (which it isn't), the more logical conclusion is the one the other two answerers mention. The reason is simple: there's five people on the floor (per team) in a basketball game at a time. James plus whoever else plus Ingram, Ball, and Kuzma will make up the starting 5.

Comment: @cjl750  No, I am not talking about any sort of mentorship, simply a pairing of two players who frequently team up on-court to achieve sometimes unbelievable results. Think LeBron James and Dwyane Wade when they played for Miami Heat, or Michael Jordan and Scottie Pippen playing for the Bulls.

Comment: That is fair, but I still think the real pairing is between the three returning players and the two newcomers.

Comment: James, no, if it were a specific pairing of a single set of two players, it would *need* to be "or" and "and" would not be acceptable at all, which is what caused @dan's confusion in the first place. The "and" is acceptable because that's not what the writer meant.

Comment: @lly 1  I did not say there would be a pairing between a single set of two players. I said "James and Fred [will be] joining the Lakers, and they will **each be individually paired** with **one player each** from a group of existing players comprised of Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball and Kyle Kuzma." (Bolding added)  So two pairings, one for each of the new players, with two other players from a  group of three named players. One of these three will not be paired, at least not with one of the new players.  'And' is required because the pairs will be selected from a group comprised of A, B and C.

Comment: @cjl750 That's fair enough. I am not claiming that my interpretation is correct, or that no other interpretation is possible. The original sentence was poorly written, leaving numerous possible interpretations. I am just doing my best to try to determine what the writer tried to say.

Comment: @James So you said there would be two pairings between two sets of two players. Makes no difference: "or" is correct and "and" simply wrong.

Comment: I am not the only one to think as I do, as I am sure that there are others will agree with you. So we will all just have to  agree to disagree.