# How to express cross pairing between two groups?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-choice

Assume that we have two smalls: Group 1 and 2.

Group 1 has two members: A1 and A2;

Group 2 has three members: B1, B2 and B3;

I want to do cross-pairing based on some unknown criteria. The result could be any of these cases:

- A1-B1, A2-B2;
- A1-B1, A2-B3;
- A1-B2, A2-B1;
- A1-B2, A2-B3;
- A1-B3, A2-B1;
- A1-B3, A2-B2;

Which is the correct/idiomatic sentence to describe the cross-pairing?

> 1. I want to pair A1 and A2 with B1, B2 and B3.
> 2. I want to pair A1 or A2 with B1, B2 or B3.

If both are improper, what's the correct way?

And if Group 1 just consists of one member: A1, then should the sentence be written as?

> 3. I want to pair A1 with B1, B2 or B3.
> 4. I want to pair A1 with B1, B2 and B3.

---

**Note**: the question is based off [my previous post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/171010/and-vs-or-in-this-sentence), where the author put:

> The team can pair James — and whoever else might be coming — with Brandon Ingram, Lonzo Ball **and** Kyle Kuzma.

I was confused with the usage of **and** in that sentence. That's why I want to ask it as a general question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to specify the exact pairing, a suitable wording might be:

> I want to pair each of A1 and A2 with an item from B1, B2 and B3.

If you do want to specify the exact pairing, you could use **[respectively](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/respectively)**: for A1-B1 and A2-B2 would would say:

> I want to pair A1 and A2 with B1 and B2 respectively.